# Slow expanding and collapsing TreeView nodes

Tags: xaml, uwp

When a node in TreeView contains many elements, like above 2000, its expanding and collapsing is very slow. For ListView I was using incremental loading:

```
<ListView
   Width="500"
   MaxHeight="400"
   IsItemClickEnabled = "False"
   SelectionMode ="None"
   IncrementalLoadingThreshold="5"
   IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"/>
```

However I do not see such option for TreeView. How this can be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Slow expanding and collapsing TreeView nodes

Both `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` do not contain IncrementalLoading behavior, so you can't make increment loading for treeview. But you could porcess data soure with linq select-take method to implement Incremental loading function.

placing a button in the last TreeViewItem that used to load more items.

For example

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
    <TreeViewItem AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}" IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="20" Source="../Assets/file.png" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            <Button Background="White" Margin="15,0,0,0" x:Name="LoadMore"  Visibility="{Binding IsLastItem}" 
                    Command="{Binding  LoadMoreCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="More"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Code Behind**

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<object>(this, (s, e) =>
{
    var temp = subitems.Skip(subitems.IndexOf(e as ExplorerItem)+1).Take(20);
    (e as ExplorerItem).IsLastItem = false;
    foreach (var item in temp)
    {            
        folder1.Children.Add(item);
    }
    folder1.Children.Last().IsLastItem = true;

});
```

[image]

For complete code, please refer to this [link](https://ruphg-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/vzhumin_teng_ai/EdyGCgxP2n9OkkkwbmXVe-oB1EQo_l_CLB5fMu0JeZ1AAA?e=EpTTVZ).